# Is there any way to put my whole Recycle Bin on one hard drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, recycle-bin

Using Windows 10, I notice that each drive on my system has its own recycle bin. Is there any way to override this behavior and put the entire recycle bin on one drive, e.g. a hard drive, so as to avoid taking up valuable space on other drives, e.g. a SSD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why you cannot do that

This is not possible by design. Moving a file within one filesystem (drive, partition) is a very fast operation: the file itself stays where it is, only gets a different name when moved. Moving a file to the Recycle Bin is in fact same as moving it to any other folder: the Recycle Bin is just a directory at the root of the drive, only hidden, called `$Recycle.Bin`. You can see it from the command prompt by adding the `/a` switch to the `dir` command:

```
C:\>dir /a $Rec*
[..snip..]
 Directory of C:\

2019-06-24  21:44    <DIR>          $Recycle.Bin
[..snip..]
C:\>cd $Recycle.Bin

C:\$Recycle.Bin>
```

It's structured in a special way, with a subdirectory for each user, so if you do `dir /a` again, you'll see funnily named directories, each actually identifying a user or some system service.

Moving files onto another drive necessarily means *copying* the whole file contents to that drive and then *deleting* the original. This is why each drive has its own `$Recycle.bin` directory.

#### What you *can* do

1. You can limit the size of the Recycle Bin. When the size is exceeded, Explorer deletes some files from RB, usually the oldest sitting there, to make space for files that it moves into it.
2. You can even turn RB off entirely for a drive, so that files are deleted immediately. I usually do not: errors happen.
3. You can clean RB at any time. It's usually not a big deal, unless you have some automatic process, like downloading files overnight, only to wake up to a "disk full" error.

If you want to limit or turn off RB, right-click on its icon (on the desktop or in Explorer, it's all the same), and select *Properties...* In the dialog, you can change the maximum size you want to allow for RB, or turn it off completely:

[image: Recycle Bin Properties dialog]

Properties are changed *per drive*, except for the delete confirmation, which is global. By default, the maximum size is 5% of disk capacity, as you can see: I never changed it on this notebook. "Space available" is a misnomer: it's the total drive size, not the free space on it.

It's probably a very good idea to enable delete confirmation if you decide to turn off Recycle Bin completely.

You can also empty RB *on all drives at once* from the same right-click menu.

Answer (score 2):

No, Windows does not permit that, but you can move a file to a folder named _Circular_File on the HDD instead of deleting it, then periodically empty the _Circular_File folder.

[Creating a custom item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769228/2909179) in the Context (right-click) menu of Windows Explorer may be a useful convenience for this.